# Getting undefined instead of the return value of a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this simple array of two objects where I need to get the price of the products of 1 month.

The array can 2 or 3 items so I'm checking whether it is 2 or 3. Then I'm storing the objects in their own variable and calling the function `getOneMonthPrice` with parameter value of those variables.

The function `getOneMOnthPrice` loops over the products and checks if the months property as a value of `01 month`, and if it does then it returns the price.

But right now I'm only getting undefined, whereas if I use console.log inside the functions, I can see the values showing in the console.

What is going wrong here?

Please note that I have actually removed most of the codes from the actual project where I'm working on. This is just the shortest version. If you can please give me a solutoin based on this format.

Here's the snippet:

```js
const arr = [{
    "name": "Boom Boom Ltd.",
    "products": [{
        "price": "3.33",
        "months": "24 months"
      },
      {
        "price": "10.95",
        "months": "01 month"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Bam Bam Ltd.",
    "products": [{
        "price": "5.93",
        "months": "24 months"
      },
      {
        "price": "12.95",
        "months": "01 month"
      }
    ]
  }
];


function getOneMonthPrice(company) {
  company.products.forEach(item => {
    if (item.months === "01 month") {
      return item.price;
    }
  });
};


if (arr.length === 2) {
  const company1 = arr[0];
  const company2 = arr[1];

  console.log(getOneMonthPrice(company1));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Returning from the `forEach` callback function doesn't return from the containing function.

Instead of `forEach`, you can use `find()` to find the array element that matches your criteria, then return the price from that.

```
function getOneMonthPrice(company) {
  let product = company.products.find(item => item.months === "01 month");
  return product && product.price;
}
```

Comment: Hey man thanks for your time. Just for learning purposes, can you tell me what could have been done if I really wanted to use forEach?

Comment: See the other answer.

Comment: But why would you really want to use `forEach`?

Comment: Okay. Last question regarding your answer. Why did you return both the product object && its price? Returning only product.price would have been enough right?

Comment: I don't. Just to know if there's actually a way to do this with forEach.

Comment: I do that in case no product is found. If I just return `product.price` it will get an error if `product == null`

Comment: @A.Amit you can't short circuit, or stop, a forEach, so there's no value in doing it with a foreach for most, if not all, scenarios.

Comment: It's roughly equivalent to `if (product) return product.price;`

Comment: Understood. Thanks a lot for your answer. I'm confused which one to choose now.

Comment: You should choose mine because it stops searching as soon as it finds the month. `forEach` will keep processing the rest of the array.

Comment: @A.Amit Choose Barmar's. His is the better answer unless you break out of your forEach.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot. And I have not been downvoting it btw just to let you guys know.